# Setting up multitenant saas solution with limits

Tags: multi-tenant, saas

A friend wants to start a new project with me.  It is a kind of POS solution for a specific kind of retail store but will be cloud hosted.  The issue we are debating is as follows:

Suppose a person owns a chain of 12 shops and he wants to buy/subscribe to our software.  But this person is cheap and doesn't want to register and pay for all 12 shops.  How do we prevent him from buying only 5 subscriptions but being able to access it from all 12 locations?

My initial thought it to require IP registration so that if he buys a 5-store subscription then he can only have 5 distinct IP addresses able to access the software at a time.  I can see how this could be a tad messy but would seem to be fairly effective.

Two questions:
1.  What are the drawbacks of this IP registration methodology?
2.  What other alternative solutions exist?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the VPN answer to Q1, although they may not have the technical ability to do it. Either way, restricting by IP is messy, especially as they're not always static - even for businesses.

As it's SaaS, I would change the license model to be based on concurrent connections. So you restrict the number of sessions they can have at any given time. If they buy five licenses, they can log in from five terminals at a time, no more.

You could also give them 5 different logins, and restrict each to only one session at a time - so they can't log in with an account on more than one device. Achieves the same thing, but may be easier to set up, depending on your software.

The latter has an additional benefit of added security - nobody else can log in with their credentials while they're using it.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: There's a quick and simple workaround for by-passing IP registration: VPN.  All that needs to be done is route all requests to head office via the VPN: all requests then appear to you to be coming from the head office.

Q2: none come to mind.